# Present perfect or simple past: changed vs have changed

Tags: grammar

I know that there are situations I can use either simple past and present perfect.

For example:

> I **changed** my mind. I can go out with you for dinner tonight.
>
> -> This sentence focuses that the change happened at some time in the past

> I **have changed** my mind. I can go out with you for dinner tonight.
>
> -> This sentence focuses on the present consequence, that is now my mind is different and I have a new decision now.

I have another example:

One of my mother’s friend haven’t seen me for 5 years. Today, she comes to my house and meets me, she will say:

You **(have changed)/(changed)** a lot, Jane. Now you are a pretty lady.

I know that we use present perfect for a past action has consequence on the present. Here the change happened in the past, the consequence in the present is that now I am a pretty lady. So that the present perfect is a good choice here.

But I am still wonder if the simple past is still fine to use here? Because I just want put the focus on a past action.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound a very tactful thing to say, as it implies that you were ugly five years ago!

She would say **"You have changed"**, because if she hasn't seen you for five years she doesn't know when the change happened, she only sees what you look like now. (I'm British - I don't know whether an American would express it differently.)

Comment: I think that although she haven’t met me for the last 5 years, but she still understand that the change happened in the past ( the change can’t happening now) . That past changed causes a present impact.

Comment: Well, of course she knows it happened in the past! But she doesn't know at what point in those five years it happened, or if it was gradual.

Comment: "I lost my key". Can you help me call a locksmith? 
Here I don't know the exact time I lost my key. but I still can use the simple past.

Comment: **I** would say "I've lost my key", but an American might use the simple past.